# Use click on table cell in subview to populate a field in the view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, view, partial-views

I have a partial view with a grid of project data.  When the user enters a client into a textbox on the main view, the partialview loads as a subview to display a table of the data for all projects for that client. Two of the columns of the table are a "select" image and the project number.  If the select image cell of a row is clicked, I would like to populate a textbox on my main view with the project number for that row.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use jQuery:

```
$('.selectImage').click(function() {
    // an element with class="selectImage" was clicked
    // we try to fetch the value of the project number
    var projectNumber = $(this).closest('tr').find('.projectNumber').text();
    $('#selectedProjectNumber').val(projectNumber);
});
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3P3Uj/1/).

As an alternative approach you could use HTML5 data-* attributes on the select image DOM element to store the project number. For example:

```
<td class="selectImage" data-project-number="123">select image</td>
```

and then you could fetch this project number like this:

```
$('.selectImage').click(function() {
    // an element with class="selectImage" was clicked
    // we try to fetch the value of the project number
    var projectNumber = $(this).data('projectNumber');
    $('#selectedProjectNumber').val(projectNumber);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/prPpR/).

Comment: Yes, I meant using jquery.  Don't know how I managed to leave that out of the question.

Comment: It's not catching the click of the cell on the subview.  How do I reference the subview's clicks?

Comment: @RememberME, what are you talking about? Any chance to see your markup?

Comment: The table is on a partial view.  The textbox I want to populate with the project number is on the main view.

Comment: Got it `$(".selectImg").live('click', function () {`  Thanks for your help!